# Arrays.sort just not sorting for whatever reason

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Right, I'm having an issue with this snippet of code, and for the life of me can't figure out what's going on:

```
String test = "Test";
char[] charArray = test.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(charArray);
for(char a:charArray)
{
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

For whatever reason this just isn't sorting my array at all and I've run out of reasons why it wouldn't be doing what I was expecting it to do? Anyone know why it's not doing this?

Comment: What is it printing out instead?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is sorted because `T` is *smaller* than `t`. if you want to sort regardless they are uppercase or lowercase, try

```
char[] charArray = test.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(charArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java, if you do:

```
if('T' < 't') {
   System.out.println("Yes");
} else {
   destroyTheWorld(); //We are safe
}
```

It will print "Yes".

`'T'` is "smaller" than `'t'`, see the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) table for details.

Possible solution is writing your own comparator.

Answer (score 1):

It is sorting the array. You just don't realize it. 'T' comes before 'e' then comes 's' then comes 't'. check character and their values. Your array is already sorted when you create it.

Answer (score 0):

Your selected input is already sorted.

```
String test = "Test123"; // <-- this will output 1,2,3,T,e,s,t with your current code.
```